# Get min,max and avg per hour of the created_at time

Tags: php, datetime

I have a table with a field created_at with the following values:

```
2017-06-06 13:04:50
2017-06-06 13:09:54
2017-06-06 13:20:20
2017-06-06 13:40:29
2017-06-06 14:05:30
2017-06-06 14:12:50
2017-06-06 14:30:40
2017-06-06 15:01:36
2017-06-06 15:06:16
```

What I want is to create a new table and do the following thing:
I want to get per hour the min, max and average and save it into another table.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Convert all Dates to UNIX_TIME() sum up the Timestamps and divide the Result trough the Amount of Dates. Then convert the Result back into a readable Format.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know where to start

Comment: @Nubcake so none of the answers was helpful in any way? Maybe you can edit your question so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for you.
I make new date values with `Y-m-d H` values.
Since I remove the minutes and seconds all times in the same hour will be duplicates.

The I count the duplicate values with array count values.

https://3v4l.org/690ne

```
$arr = array("2017-06-06 13:04:50",
"2017-06-06 13:09:54",
"2017-06-06 13:20:20",
"2017-06-06 13:40:29",
"2017-06-06 14:05:30",
"2017-06-06 14:12:50",
"2017-06-06 14:30:40",
"2017-06-06 15:01:36",
"2017-06-06 15:06:16");

Foreach($arr as $val){
    $newarr[] = date("Y-m-d H", strtotime($val));
}

Var_dump($newarr);

Var_dump(array_count_values($newarr));
```

Output of above code is:

> array(9) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 13"
>     [1]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 13"
>     [2]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 13"
>     [3]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 13"
>     [4]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 14"
>     [5]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 14"
>     [6]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 14"
>     [7]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 15"
>     [8]=>
>     string(13) "2017-06-06 15"
>   }
>   array(3) {
>     ["2017-06-06 13"]=>
>     int(4)
>     ["2017-06-06 14"]=>
>     int(3)
>     ["2017-06-06 15"]=>
>     int(2)
>   }

Edit reading David's answer it seems it was unclear what "per hour" means.
David reads it as one hour rolling time.
I read it as between 13-14, between 14-15 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

IMO integers are easier to manipulate than datetime. Step 1 convert values to timestamps. Then it is a matter of mathematical operations such as

- min: http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php
- max: http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
- average: add all, divide by count

Once you have the three values use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php to insert the data to a table.

(Note: DO NOT USE the mysql database extension!)